# Excel - Target Line on Graph from just 1 Data Point

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I am trying to chart out actual (performance) data points against target on a graph. Is there a way to produce the target line from just 1 value? It would be assumed all the performance variables would be put against that target. I just don't want to create another row below the performance data row, with a corresponding target for each because the target is the same for all those data points. However in graphing, Excel thinks there is only one data point for target in that series, so it only graphs that one point. I would like it to instead graph it for every performance data point, but just put the target in one cell. The reason for this is really just to streamline the data entry and compress that sheet by not having to add the helper rows.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You can use a horizontal error bar for this. But you must define the length of this bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an additional data series to define your target graph.

If you have a hard time determining values for that data-series, look into e.g. `linear regression` for that type of x-to-y correlation; i.e. to create "starter values" based on your actual data.